# disabling struts2 jquery datepicker button image

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, struts2-jquery

i have following date picker

```
window.onload=function ff(){

    $('#date_row').load('load.jsp');

}

function one(){ 

    $('#date_row10').datepicker('disable');
    $('#date_row00').datepicker('disable');

}

sj:datepicker value="today" id="date_row00" name="optionList[0].optionAmtDateList[0].date" size="10" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" duration="fast" onchange="one()" minDate="today" maxDate="today+9" readonly="true"

<div id="date_row"/>
```

in load.jsp i have another calender like the code

```
sj:datepicker value="today" id="date_row10" name="optionList[1].optionAmtDateList[0].date" size="10" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" duration="fast" onchange="" minDate="today" maxDate="today+9" readonly="true"
```

it's working for disable the calender from another page, but not disabled the calender in first page

so how to disable datepicker button in first page.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GyM7j/ where is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Button is not disabled ,when i am clicking on button the datepicker disaplaying, i want to disable don't want show

Comment: actually the problem is i am loading one more calender from other page using the code $('#date_row').load('load.jsp'); in load.jsp i have another calender with different ID , so after loading that i am trying to disable both calenders. so another calender is disabled but the calender in first page not disabled

Comment: now i written total code Irvin ,please give the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try change your approach, remove the inline event handler `one`; then set a class on your datepicker fields (e.g. calendar) and set a delegate event handler for the change event using `on`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker, #datepicker2").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });

    $('body').on('change', '.calendar', function () {
        $(this).datepicker('disable');
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/r9yLs/

Comment: Hi,in my requirement both datepickers are in different pages,not in one page,because i have to pass the date selected in first pick as mindate in second pick(i.e the starting date in 2nd pick decide depends on selected date in first pick) ,so i taken both pick's in different pages.so when i load the second pick page then i pass the selected value of first pick.